# Date & Time Picker with Material Design

Tags: date, time, material-design, datetimepicker

I wanted to use date picker from [this side](https://puranjayjain.github.io/md-date-time-picker/#documentation/basicexample) and I received this error:

> mdDateTimePicker.js:80 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _moment2.default) is not a function

**This is my script**

```js
var dialog = new mdDateTimePicker.default({
    type: 'date'
});
var toggleButton = document.getElementById('dataPicker');
toggleButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    dialog.toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing moment.js library to your example
Please note that moment.js must be loaded before mdDateTimePicker.js

```
<script src="js/moment.js"></script>
<script src="js/mdDateTimePicker.js"></script>
```

I also try you code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PKvDZ7nVypIXFMtoCLIN?p=preview)